# Shared injections in Guice

Tags: java, guice

I am using Guice in java.
For some modules I have noticed that I have parameters which are repeated in every provider in my module. This can become very verbose if I have several of them per provider function.

I am looking for a pattern where I can pass a shared dependency once into the module.

```
PizzasModule{
  @Provides provideMushroomPizza ( oven ,mushrooms)  {oven.bakePizza(mushrooms)}
  @Provides provideMOlivePizza   ( oven ,olives)     {oven.bakePizza(olives)}
  @Provides provideMTomatoPizza  ( oven ,tomatoes)   {oven.bakePizza(tomatoes)}

}
```

Every pizza needs to be baked in the oven.
I would like to provide it once for the module.
**How do I inject `oven` in to the code below without repeating it?**

```
PizzasModule{
  
  Oven oven; //How do I get this injected into module only once? (as opposed to the example in the previous block)

  bakePizzaInOven(topping) {oven.bakePizza(topping)}

  @Provides provideMushroomPizza (mushrooms)  {bakePizzaInOven(mushrooms)}
  @Provides provideMOlivePizza   (olives)     {bakePizzaInOven(olives)}
  @Provides provideMTomatoPizza  (tomatoes)   {bakePizzaInOven(tomatoes)}

}
```

I only want to specify `oven` once in my provider (the oven is not mine, and I only get it once I start injecting [I cannot pass it in the module constructor] ).

I can probably add a helper provider, which will provide a `pizzeria` with an oven bound to it, and a `pizzeria.bakePizzaInOven(topping)` method. But I am wondering if GUICE has a built in pattern to save me the trouble? (Also my "real code" has more then just one shared parameter)

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. Are you instantiating your `oven` *inside* the Guice module? That's really bad. Instead, just make a (singleton) binding that provides the `oven`, then`@Inject` it where needed. Provider functions in modules are allowed to have parameters, which are injected as anything else would be. If you want to make this clearer, provide the real Module code instead of the pseudo-code you have now.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited the example. The intent of the question is to avoid repeated `@Inject` parameters throughout my providers. The first example (my current code) injects an oven in each provider method. (My real code has more then 3 providers, and more then 2 parameters). The seconds psuedocode example is what I would like to have: I don't want to `@Inject` the oven 20 times all over my provider parameters. I would like to inject it once, and use it for all the providers in the module

Comment: I don't think you can do that. You are trying to mix setup (modules & provider functions) with runtime (actual injected values), which is always a bad idea.